# Apply CSS style to span in div

Tags: css, stylesheet

I've a table structure like below

```
<td id="td1">
<a href="#">
<div>
1
<div>
<span>0</span>
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
</div>
</div>
<div> </div>
</a>
</td>

<td id="td2">
<a href="#">
<div>
2
<div>
<span>0</span>
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
</div>
</div>
<div> </div>
</a>
</td>
```

And now I wanted to apply style for **span** under td1 and not to td2. Is there any way to get it don't? How can we write a CSS style for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the selector in this way: `#td1 span { /* your styles */}`

Comment: Hey it is working for me.. is there any other way to filter? like I wanted to apply style for only >0 values. For span = 0 I dont want to apply any style.

Comment: what do you mean? Would you apply the style if the span contains `1` or more? You should use javascript for that.

Comment: hmm yes, I wanted to apply for only 1 and more. For 0 value I wanted to apply different style.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/4YDzX/)

```
table tr td span {
    padding:0 5px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#117809;
    }
```

or if you want to give css to span within a particular div then following the following css. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4YDzX/1/)**

```
#td1 span {
    padding:0 5px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#DC0B0B;
    }
```

Comment: Here also I wanted to give style for only particular spans. i.e I wanted to apply different style for 0 and all other are same

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/4YDzX/2/

.red {
    background-color:#DC0B0B;
}

<span class="red">0</span>

Answer (score 2):

**Try to this**

```
#td1 span{color:green;font-weight:bold;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aGCk4/)**